# MIPS Hello World program segfaults

Tags: linux, mips

I have the following simple MIPS program

```
.text
.globl __start
__start:
    li $v0, 4004
    li $a0, 1
    la $a1, msg
    li $a2, 14
    syscall

    li $v0, 4001
    li $a0, 0
    syscall
.data
msg: .asciiz "hello, world\n"
```

I cross-compiled and ran under qemu with

```
$ clang --target=mips-linux-gnu -nostdlib -static -fuse-ld=lld test.s -o a.out
ld.lld: warning: can't find matching R_MIPS_LO16 relocation for R_MIPS_GOT16
$ qemu-mips a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Does that warning message have something to do with the segfault? Here's what the executable looks like

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[xxHash]=0e7f55e2470ade0a, not stripped
$ llvm-objdump -d a.out

/tmp/a.out: file format elf32-mips

Disassembly of section .text:

00020180 <__start>:
   20180: 24 02 0f a4   addiu   $2, $zero, 4004
   20184: 24 04 00 01   addiu   $4, $zero, 1
   20188: 8f 85 80 18   lw  $5, -32744($gp)
   2018c: 24 06 00 0e   addiu   $6, $zero, 14
   20190: 00 00 00 0c   syscall
   20194: 24 02 0f a1   addiu   $2, $zero, 4001
   20198: 24 04 00 00   addiu   $4, $zero, 0
   2019c: 00 00 00 0c   syscall
```

Note that the program without the "hello, world" syscall works as expected, without any problems

```
.text
.globl __start
__start:
    li $v0, 4001
    li $a0, 0
    syscall
.data
msg: .asciiz "hello, world\n"
```

I tried what I described above, and I expected it to print "hello, world" and exit with return code 0 but in actuality it segfaulted.

Comment: What's segfault'ing, is it the `lw` or the `syscall` — that's important.  What is the address for`msg` (should be able to tell from a debugger).  Is that value in `$a0` after the `la`?  Since you've taken over `__start`, has `$gp` been properly initialized?  Also, you're getting linker errors, so something is wrong with your global data setup.  Verify the value in `$gp`, and/or look at linker options and/or other instruction sequences to access your data (e.g. %hi(msg), %lo(msg)).  Could also be an assembler option memory model issue.

Comment: I'm just starting MIPS assembly, was I supposed to initialize $gp? What is it supposed to be initialized to? It's not the syscall that's the problem, the syscall works as expected. It's probably the fact that the address isn't pointing to the string. Probably the lw.

Comment: Ok, suggest you get hello world working from C and look at that code and use gdb to compare.  Does the C version also use `lw .. .$(gp)`.  Does the C version also get the linker warning about relocations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably too late for OP, but might be useful to someone in
the future regardless.

Note that by default clang produces SVR4-style
Position Independent Executables
(`-fPIE -mabicalls`) for MIPS Linux targets.

This implies that, in general, data accesses and function calls are made
indirectly by loading the address of the data/function label from the
Global Offset Table (GOT).
To do this, an extra instruction must be inserted by the assembler.
This can be seen when looking at the result of assembling OP's
example into a relocatable object file (i.e. without linking it)
using gcc:

```
$ mips-linux-gnu-gcc -nostdlib -static -c test.s
$ mips-linux-gnu-objdump -d --reloc test.o
   # [...]
00000000 <__start>:
   0:   24020fa4    li  v0,4004
   4:   24040001    li  a0,1
   8:   8f850000    lw  a1,0(gp)     # This is the result of the single
            8: R_MIPS_GOT16 .data    #  pseudo-instruction `la $a1, msg`
   c:   24a50000    addiu   a1,a1,0  #  <-- Note the extra instruction here
            c: R_MIPS_LO16  .data    #
  10:   2406000e    li  a2,14
  14:   0000000c    syscall
  18:   24020fa1    li  v0,4001
  1c:   24040000    li  a0,0
  20:   0000000c    syscall
    ...
```

Due to what's likely a
[bug in clang](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/65020),
no extra instruction is added when assembling the same code with clang:

```
$ clang --target=mips-linux-gnu -nostdlib -static -c test.s
$ mips-linux-gnu-objdump -d --reloc test.o
   # [...]
00000000 <__start>:
   0:   24020fa4    li  v0,4004
   4:   24040001    li  a0,1
   8:   8f850000    lw  a1,0(gp)    # While the first instruction is correctly
            8: R_MIPS_GOT16 .data   # generated, the extra instruction is missing
   c:   2406000e    li  a2,14
  10:   0000000c    syscall
  14:   24020fa1    li  v0,4001
  18:   24040000    li  a0,0
  1c:   0000000c    syscall
```

This is what causes lld to give OP's warning:

```
$ clang --target=mips-linux-gnu -nostdlib -static -fuse-ld=lld test.s
ld.lld: warning: can't find matching R_MIPS_LO16 relocation for R_MIPS_GOT16
```

Now, note that even with the correct executable produced by gcc,
the program still doesn't work (it will still segfault).
This is because the `$gp` is never initialized to the value used by
the assembler and linker: the address corresponding to the label `_gp`.
This is normally done by the system startup code (typically found in
`crt0.o` or `crt1.o`) that is linked by default,
but this is not the case here because of the `-nostdlib` flag.
The following assembly code can be added to the start of `__start` to
correctly load the `$gp`:

```
__start:
    .set    noreorder
    bal     0f
     nop
0:  .cpload $ra
    move    $ra, $zero
    .set    reorder
    # [...]
```

Even then, all functions should still be written in PIC style (more
information at https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PIC_code).

So, one solution would be to simply use the gnu
toolchain rather than llvm while the bug in clang isn't fixed.
This would require the use of the PIC-related initializations
as described above.
The following gcc command can then be used:

```
$ mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc -mno-abicalls -nostdlib -static test.s -o a.out
```

Alternatively, if the scope is just to emulate a single
statically-linked binary using QEMU's User Emulation,
then position-independent code can be avoided altogether.
The `-mno-abicalls` flag (which implies `-fno-pic`) can be
used:

```
$ clang --target=mips-linux-gnu -mno-abicalls -nostdlib -static -fuse-ld=lld test.s -o a.out
```

This alleviates the overhead of PIC, including the
`$gp`-related intializations.
However, to use gp-relative addressing to access
the small data sections (`.sdata`, `.sbss`),
it is still necessary to initialize the `$gp` at startup as seen above.